# "Aw, Snap!" error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I need some help.

I'm trying to make a very simple Chrome application that, when clicked, redirects automatically to a URL in a new tab. The tab opens, and seems to load the page, but at the end I get "Aw, Snap!" error.

This is what I see:
http://gyazo.com/ef733df79e6449b22998f1cbb297d770

My code is:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Here goes the name",
  "description": "Here goes the description",
  "version": "Here goes the version",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    window.open("Here goes the URL");
});
```

I have Chrome version 42.0.2311.90 m.

I uninstalled all Chrome Applications, with no results.

I deleted all cookies, with no results.

I uninstalled and installed Chrome again, with no results.

Can you tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you look in the console for any errors that your extension was throwing?

Comment: I assume that you have the actual version where it says "Here goes the version" right?

Since you have internalization, you have `_locales/en` directory and `messages.json` set up? Do you get the same result if you remove the locale bit from manifest?

Where it says "Here goes the URL" you have a full working URL right?

If all yes then it should work just fine.

Comment: @Jack, no errors in console... But thanks for the reply anyways.

Comment: @Samurai, yes, I have _locales/en with messages.json. Version and URL are correct...Thank you anyways :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my app, trying to open URL from on the notification button click via `window.open(targetUrl)` causing *Aw snap* window too. After the first error I'm getting *Aw snaps* everywhere and need to restart the Chrome. Looks like something more global.

Comment: FYI, as was OK with Extension (instead of App), I converted to extension and used `chrome.tabs.create({url: targetUrl})` for URL opening. Don't forget to request *tabs* permissions in your manifest.